# rails not updating page title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, title, railscasts

I am following [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title?view=asciicast) to update custom page title and realized that it doesn't work anymore. So, i updated the code as follows based on the comments. I see 'My Services -' if i do not set the title, whereas i expect it to contain default title value set. Any insights please?

In `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%= render 'layouts/head' %>
<!-- <body> included in yield -->
  <%= yield %>
<!-- </body> -->
</html>
```

In `_head.html.erb`

```
<head>
  <title>My services - <%= yield(:title) %> </title>
</head>
```

In `home.html.erb` [Intentionally not setting title to see default value]

```
<body></body>
```

In `application_helper.rb`

```
  def title(page_title, default="Testing")
    content_for(:title) { page_title || default }
  end
```

In `application_helper.rb`, I also tried the following solution:

```
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title || default }
  end

  def yield_for(section, default = "Testing")
    content_for?(section) ? yield(section) : default
  end
```

Any insights please?

Comment: You need an = before the yield. <%= yield...

Comment: that was a typo.. I had it in the code :)

Comment: oh, I knew that was too easy.

Comment: actually you are correct. That was the issue for the second part I mentioned ( I missed it during testing). However it doesn't work for first: def title(page_title, default="Testing")
    content_for(:title) { page_title || default }
  end. Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simplify:

```
<title>My services - <%= page_title %> </title>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def page_title
  if content_for?(:title)
    content_for(:title)
  else
    "Testing"
  end
end
```

Now, I don't think you actually want "Testing"... Really, I think you just want to not see the "-" at the end of your html page titles. So why not:

```
<title><%= html_title %></title>

def html_title
  site_name = "My services"
  page_title = content_for(:title) if content_for?(:title)
  [site_name,page_title].join(" - ")
end
```

You'll either see:

```
<title>My services</title>
```

or if you set the title like so:

```
<%= content_for(:title) { "SuperHero" } %>
```

You'll see:

```
<title>My services - SuperHero</title>
```

[#content_for?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F) is defined as:

```
#content_for? simply checks whether any content has been captured yet using #content_for Useful to render parts of your layout differently based on what is in your views.
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. the tip on content_for? is helpful. You are correct, I donot want testing, however the client wanted to see something else like, "Our Solutions". Will stick to the first part.